# RxJava 2 equivalent to isUnsubscribed

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I've been working through the examples in the book [Reactive Programming with RxJava](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reactive-Programming-RxJava-Asynchronous-Applications/dp/1491931655/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1497368108&sr=1-1&keywords=reactive%20programming%20with%20rxjava), which is targeted at version 1 not 2. An introduction to infinite streams has the following example (and notes there are better ways to deal with the concurrency):

```
Observable<BigInteger> naturalNumbers = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    Runnabler = () -> {
        BigInteger i = ZERO;
        while (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(i);
            i = i.add(ONE);
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
});

...

Subscription subscription = naturalNumbers.subscribe(x -> log(x));
/* after some time... */
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

However, in RxJava 2, the lambda expression passed to the `create()` method is of type `ObservableEmitter` and this doesn't have an `isUnsubscribed()` method. I've had a look in [What's Different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) and also performed a search of the repository but can't find any such method.

How would this same functionality be achieved in 2.0?

**Edited to include solution as given below (n.b. using kotlin):**

```
val naturalNumbers = Observable.create<BigInteger> { emitter ->
    Thread({
        var int: BigInteger = BigInteger.ZERO
        while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
            emitter.onNext(int)
            int = int.add(BigInteger.ONE)
        }
    }).start()
}

val first = naturalNumbers.subscribe { log("First: $it") }
val second = naturalNumbers.subscribe { log("Second: $it") }

Thread.sleep(5)
first.dispose()
Thread.sleep(5)
second.dispose()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you subscribe to Observable, `Disposable` is returned. You can save it to your local variable and check `disposable.isDisposed()` to see if it still subscribing or not.